# Meaning of "How do I respond when confronted by a person you spoke ill about me to a fault?"

Tags: meaning, sentence

> How do I respond when confronted by a person you spoke ill about me to a fault?

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Beat him to a pulp?

Answer (score 1):

From wikitionary:  "'To a fault' is ordinarily used to modify an adjective which describes some desirable or otherwise positive characteristic of a person."

So "spoke ill about me to a fault" sounds like someone's misapprehension of the meaning of "to a fault."

Short answer: Ignore the "to a fault" clause. The writer likely meant:

> How do I respond when confronted by a person of whom you spoke poorly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a 'fused syllepsis' for

> How do I respond when confronted by a person you spoke ill about me
>   to, to a fault?

a better rephrasing would be

> How do I respond when confronted by a person to whom you were really
>   critical of me?

Comment: I will have to look up the definition of "syllepsis". :) Thank you for your answer!!  As soon as I am able to "vote up" your answer I will.

Comment: There's debate over the difference between 'zeugma' and 'syllepsis'. Suffice to say that 'He took his hat and his leave' is an example of one or the other (or both), with 'took' doing incongruous 'double duty' literally and idiomatically (took his hat / took his leave). The sentence here likewise seems to press 'to' into incongruous double duty. However, I'd say that omitting one 'to' also makes it ungrammatical in this case. So I've modified 'syllepsis' in my answer to 'fused syllepsis' (which you won't find in the dictionary:-) )